# Get Current Animation Frame or Sprite Name

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 2D, is there a way to get the current sprite used either by a SpriteRenderer or an Animation? The idea I have is to have multiple GameObjects to use for a player character, and from the main one which receives animations and the script, edit the others based on the sprite currently used.

Now, I know that to get the current sprite name I can do this:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.name
```

But that will only return the sprite used for the main GameObject's SpriteRenderer, and the name of it would not change even as animation changes it in Game Mode

Answer (score 0):

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.name
```

This 100% does work , just tried it now and it is changing the name for each current sprite that the animator is changing.

You need to give more information and maybe a video since there is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: So, on the script, I have this `private Sprite currentSprite;` then inside `Awake` I have `currentSprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;`, and on the first line inside `Update` I have this `Debug.Log(currentSprite.name);` to show the sprite name but it's always the first one.

Comment: @gfcf14 You need to get the sprite object in the `Update`, otherwise you are always reading a reference to the same object